# javascript equivalent to a python print?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Beginner question here for someone on day 1 starting out on learning tutorials for javascript. Does javascript have something similar to a `print` in Python?

I am not using a web browser to learn .js (but maybe I should?) but just a text editor for a file `test.js` with the code:

```
function test(){
    var a = "3";
    var b = "8";
    

    console.log("a is ", + a);
    console.log("b is ", + b);
    
}
```

And then in Windows terminal just running the file from node, `node test.js`

But nothing prints, I assume console.log is for browser only... Thanks for any tips

Comment: You're not calling `test()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call your function

```js
function test(){
    var a = "3";
    var b = "8";
    

    console.log("a is ", + a);
    console.log("b is ", + b);
    
}
test()
```

Comment: Ah ha thank you much ill git the green check